# Javascript Condition when a form is ready and validated

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a script to activate when a button is clicked, it is to change the action of the form when submitting.

```
 $("#Preview").click(function(){
     $(this).closest("form").attr("action","PreviewNews.php");
 });
```

but i want to add extra condition which is, When the form is ready and Validated through validation. Basically is short is when button is click and form are done validated then script will run.
How to do this? is there a condition for this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery validation plugin? or just custom validation functions?

Comment: Just exactly what you see, nothing more then a custom validation. Just want to know if there is a condition like $("form").Validated() or something like it

Comment: JS cannot validate your form unless you tell it what to validate for each field. There are two ways you can do this. 
1) User jQuery Validation plugin.
2) Provide appropriate input type for HTML5 to validate the form before submitting. For example: for an email text box, use input type="email"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add validation of form in onclick function:

```
$("#Preview").click(function(){
if($("#fieldid").val()=="") {
return false;
}
$(this).closest("form").attr("action");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just make a validation function and return true if validation is succesfull
and put a if condition if validation is true execute the script inside if , if not render something or just not run the script

```
var validate = validate(){
if(){
return true;
}else 
 return false;
}

if(validate){
    //Run script here
}
```